# Express.js why does placement of app.use() affect test results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am practicing my knowledge in Express.js .

I have one recipe router with the code below:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const Recipe = require("../models/recipe.model");

const createRecipeItem = async recipeData => {
  await Recipe.init();
  const doc = Recipe(recipeData);
  await doc.save();
};

router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await createRecipeItem(req.body);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
  res.status(201).send(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have another supply router, the code is below:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const Supply = require("../models/supply.model");

const createSupplyItem = async supplyData => {
  await Supply.init();
  const doc = Supply(supplyData);
  await doc.save();
};

const updateItem = async (name, itemData) => {
  const result = await Supply.findOneAndUpdate({ name }, itemData, {
    new: true
  });
  return result;
};

router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await createSupplyItem(req.body);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
  const respObj = {};
  respObj.name = req.body.name;
  respObj.qty = req.body.qty;
  res.status(201).send(respObj);
});

router.patch("/:name", async (req, res, next) => {
  const updatedItem = await updateItem(req.params.name, req.body);
  const response = {};
  response.name = updatedItem.name;
  response.qty = updatedItem.qty;
  res.status(200).send(response);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I wrote tests for the two routers using [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest)

Inside my app.js my code is written like this:

```
const supplyRouter = require("./routes/supply.route");
const recipeRouter = require("./routes/recipe.route");

app.use("/recipes", recipeRouter);
app.use("/supplies", supplyRouter);
```

when the code is written like this:

```
app.use("/recipes", recipeRouter);
app.use("/supplies", supplyRouter);
```

All my test passed. However, when I change the order of when I call `app.use()` the test would fail.

```
app.use("/supplies", supplyRouter);
app.use("/recipes", recipeRouter);
```

The test would fail with the error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` for the `POST /supplies` method. I have no clear understanding why this happens. Appreciate any insight. Thank you!

Comment: This is most likely due to you calling `res.someMethod` more than once for a single request, meaning if, for example, you call `next(error)` and then `res.status(...).send(...)` in the same request, the `next(error)` (depending on the implementation of your error handler) might also call `res.status(...).send(...)` at some point and that's why you're seeing this error. Make sure to do "stop" your code when it's supposed to stop, i.e. with an early `return`, and also make sure you're handling on your errors appropriately when using `async/await`, i.e. in `router.patch("/:name")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot pass my test correctly because I didn't have proper understanding of the flow of the code.

```
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await createSupplyItem(req.body);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
  const respObj = {};
  respObj.name = req.body.name;
  respObj.qty = req.body.qty;
  res.status(201).send(respObj);
});
```

For the above code, when there is an error, express will run two paths of the code namely the path inside the `catch` block  and the last line of the code 
`res.status(201).send(respObj);`

Because it is trying to run two paths, I received the error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

The correct code is written below.

```
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await createSupplyItem(req.body);
    const respObj = {};
    respObj.name = req.body.name;
    respObj.qty = req.body.qty;
    res.status(201).send(respObj);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
      err.statusCode = 400;
    } else if (err.name === "MongoError") {
      err.statusCode = 400;
    }
    next(err);
  }
});
```